# c++ get remote process peb modules

Tags: c++, dll, windows-kernel

hi guys i build a kernel driver and i use it to get PEB of process with out handle
i successfuly get the peb and i know it from the imageBaseAddress

when i enumerate on the modules (PEB_LDR_DATA and LIST_ENTRY)
i get the modules of my process why?? (ishuld get the remote process modules)

here is the code to get the peb

```
BOOL GetRemotePeb(IN HANDLE process_handle, OUT PEB* ppeb) {
    if (hDriver == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return FALSE;

    ULONG bytes;
    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi;

    if (QueryInformationProcess(process_handle, ProcessBasicInformation, &pbi, sizeof(PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION), &bytes)) {
        if (ReadVirtualMemory(process_handle, pbi.PebBaseAddress, ppeb, sizeof(PEB), NULL)) {
            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
    else
        return FALSE;
}
```

here is the code enumerate the modules

```
if (Driver.ProcessInformation("ac_client.exe", &pi)) {
    if (Driver.GetRemotePeb(pi.UniqueProcessId, &peb)) {
        for (PLIST_ENTRY pListEntry = (PLIST_ENTRY)((PPEB_LDR_DATA)peb.Ldr)->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink;
            pListEntry != (PLIST_ENTRY)((PPEB_LDR_DATA)peb.Ldr)->Reserved2[2]; pListEntry = (PLIST_ENTRY)pListEntry->Flink)
        {
            PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY pEntry = CONTAINING_RECORD(pListEntry, LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, Reserved1[0]);
            printf("[ %d ] Name: %ls.\n", ++modulesCount,pEntry->FullDllName.Buffer);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know: what is a pointer?

Comment: So you call `Driver.GetRemotePeb(123456, &peb)` and it tells you that the PEB in process 123456 is at address 0x789ABCDE for example. Then you access address 0x789ABCDE  in *your* process. Who says it's the same thing at that address? Read about what virtual memory is.

Comment: sory guys but lets relax a bit, i not a idiot ok @user253751 yes i know what is a pointer.!!
i build my on driver and i get all the information i need but. i just want to improve it.

Comment: the problem is thet i get my on process moduls why ??

Comment: because you are accessing the memory of your own process?

Comment: @user253751 you see this line " Driver.ProcessInformation("ac_client.exe", &pi) " so how you can ask this question????

Comment: the base address of "ac_client.exe" is correct and i get it from the peb

Comment: yes, and then you access that address in your own process, not in ac_client.exe.

Comment: "where do you live at?" "number 35" "then how come when I go to number 35 I get my own house?" "because you're going to number 35 on your street instead of my street"